# Configure embedded Neo4j cluster with neo4j-ogm 2.x (EmbeddedDriver)

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I'm using Spring-data-neo4j 4.1.0.RC1 and neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver 2.0.1 and 
I'm trying to configure my embedded database in HA cluster mode (server id, initial hosts, push factor, ...).

Is there a way to do it ? I'm not able to do it via the DriverConfiguration class.

With Spring-data-neo4j 3.x, I was able to to override Neo4jConfiguration.graphDatabase() method to configure my own GraphDatabaseService with help of HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory.

Thank you !

Comment: Hey if you're an Neo4j enterprise customer, please raise this as a Sev3 ticket in the support system too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 11 Nov, 2016**

This is now enabled. Please see https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/142 for details.

<del>Support for HA using the Embedded Driver is not currently available. I've raised a ticket for it, https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/142.</del>